# Substitute for "synchronized" keyword in Java for multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

can you check if this code will be thread safe/ replace synchronization's features? like restricting access to multiple threads?

```
class CheckSynch{

  public static booloean check=true;

  public static void func() // I am trying to write alternative code for synchronized function
  {
     if(check) {
       check=false;
       //body of function
       check=true;
       notifyAll();
     } else {
       wait();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: trust me, you don't need to write an alternative to the synchronized keyword.  There are people much smarter than you that have already designed this well, no offense.

Comment: This code won't even run, let alone be thread safe.  wait/notify has to be inside a synchronized block, otherwise you have nothing to wait or notify on.

Answer (score 7):

Anything that doesn't use proper synchronization is bound to break. If you have two hardware threads, they will run concurrently, so in the time between `check` being checked and modified, a different thread could have come along and changed it.

I don't know why you're trying to shun `synchronized`, but whatever you're trying to do with unsynchronized functions, it won't work and will eventually break in very hard-to-reproduce bugs.

Answer (score 5):

Writing your own Locking/sychronizaton is very advanced topic, writing code which compiles is not an advanced topic.  You have to ask yourself if this really is a good idea.

You can write something like

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public static void func() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
       //body of function
    } finally {
       lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

However, you haven't said WHY you want to write you own synchronisation.  I assume it because you don't want to wait 1-2 micro-seconds it takes to acquire a lock.

You can instead use a busy loop.

```
final AtomicBoolean lock = new AtomicBoolean();

public static void func() {
    // wait for the lock to be false and set it to true.
    while(lock.getAndSet(true)); 
    try {
        // body of function
    } finally {
        lock.set(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, I believe you mean `compareAndSet(false, true)` not `getAndSet(true)`. +1 for a good alternative.

Comment: You could do a `compareAndSet` as well, but `boolean` only has two possible values. I would use whatever you feel is clearer.

Comment: @Peter, I'm trying to convince myself of how getAndSet would work as originally posted. If the value is `false` that means the lock is free. So the `while(lock.getAndSet(true))` would always fail the first time through. But then, it is like opening a flood gate. The second time through it works and so does every other attempt by every other thread until someone exits. I suppose it would work if the values were inverted...

Comment: The first thread to see that it is `false`, sets it to `true` and breaks out of the loop.  Every other thread will see `true` and will continue to do so until a thread sets it to `false`.

Comment: I've grown too used to seeing the same patterns ... get the value, do something on it, try a CAS... repeat until succeeding.

Comment: getAndSet uses compareAndSet, I thought it was simpler in this case.

Answer (score 2):

no, wait() needs to be in a synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

Its always advisable to avoid the `synchronized` block in a static method.

i agree with EboMike, although if you are looking to block threads based on read/write criteria.. you can always use the  [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: It may be worth explaining why it is advisable to "avoid the synchronized block in a static method."